# Issues with new graphics card and drivers

Tags: drivers, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

With my onboard graphics card (Intel HD 4000) I was able to use 1680x1050 screen resolution. Using the same screen and an Asus ENGTS250 graphics card with 296.10 drivers installed, I'm not able to use that resolution anymore.

Also, I've been having other trouble with driver installations. Using 340.52 or 337.88, I can't boot into Windows 7.
I see the Windows Welcome screen and then the screen goes black, loses signal and the computer locks up.

I think the drivers issues and the resolution problems go hand-in-hand. I have a feeling I could use a newer driver than 296.10 which would give me access to use the 1680x1050 resolution I want to use, but I'm terrified that if I update or install another driver, that the computer will lock up again.

Can anyone recommend a [better] driver for me to use?

Comment: I see the question getting downvotes, can anyone suggest how I can improve it?

Comment: By reading the list of [valid topics](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.